# wxTreebook with multiple levels

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a wxTreebook object with multiple (3 in particular) levels of pages but it seems to be imposible.

Can anyone say if one can create such objects with wxTreebook or it is necessaryto use wxTreeCtrl?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlfPl.png)
This here is want i want it to look.

Comment: did you look at the notebook sample? Build it, riun it, then come back if you still have questions. Or better yet - draw a sketch of what you want and drop it here.

Comment: yes, I did, however i want to use treebook not notebook as it looks better

Comment: run the sample and look thru the menu. You can switch to the wxTreebook from there. But as said - sketch is the best option...

Comment: Post your code. In [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) form. Then maybe we can answer.

Comment: Don't post images of text, code or whatever can be shown in plain text format.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, any "text-drawing" will be screwed after pressing "OK". It is OK to post a picture, it is actually encouraged to do so. Otherwise there wouldn't be a link to post a picture in the "Question Post" toolbar.

Comment: @Igor Sure, images can be OK if there's no better way to present the information. But, in this case, the image was of a directory tree, that could as well has been rendered as text.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, are you sure about that? My understanding is that the OP native is Russian, just like mine. And I know a log of people like me have trouble expressing the question in English. And 2nd - the picture worth a thousand words. Picture - not a text drawing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxTreebook` is indeed limited to a single level of depth because it was thought that having deeper nesting would be too confusing for the users. So you will have to use a standalone `wxTreeCtrl` to achieve what you want -- although perhaps simplifying the hierarchy and using `wxTreebook` could be a better idea from the UI point of view.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess that's what I'll do!